# k-Medoids clustering problems

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to get k-Medoids clustering to work on some time series data with horizontal linear trends. When I run the algorithm, it identifies vertical clusters and not horizontal ones - [for example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LKatT.jpg)

I thought it was the distance algorithm initially, but I have used the same function with kmeans clustering and it works okay. So the bug may be in the kmedoids function but I cannot find it. data is 2xN array (timestamp, value), k = 6 (number of clusters), and the max iterations is 100.

Can anyone help?

```
function [centroids, assignments] = kMedoids(data, k, maxIterations)
    % Initialize centroids randomly
    numSamples = size(data, 1);
    centroidIndices = randperm(numSamples, k);
    centroids = data(centroidIndices, :);
    % Perform k-medoids clustering
    for iteration = 1:maxIterations
        % Assign samples to the nearest centroid
        distances = pdist2(data, centroids, 'euclidean'); 
        [~, assignments] = min(distances, [], 2);
        % Update centroids
        for i = 1:k
            centroidSamples = data(assignments == i, :);
            numCentroidSamples = size(centroidSamples, 1);
            totalDistance = sum(pdist2(centroidSamples, centroidSamples, 'euclidean'), 'all');
            % Try swapping each sample with the current centroid and calculate the total distance
            for j = 1:numCentroidSamples
                newCentroid = centroidSamples(j, :);
                newTotalDistance = sum(pdist2(centroidSamples, newCentroid, 'euclidean'), 'all');
                % If the new total distance is lower, update the centroid
                if newTotalDistance < totalDistance
                    totalDistance = newTotalDistance;
                    centroids(i, :) = newCentroid;
                end
            end
        end
    end
end


function distances = pdist2(X, Y, distanceMetric)
    % Check if X and Y have compatible sizes
    if size(X, 2) ~= size(Y, 2)
        error('X and Y must have the same number of columns.');
    end
    % Compute pairwise distances between vectors in X and Y
    numX = size(X, 1);
    numY = size(Y, 1);
    distances = zeros(numX, numY);
    for i = 1:numX
        for j = 1:numY
            distances(i, j) = calculateDistance(X(i, :), Y(j, :), distanceMetric);
        end
    end
end

function distance = calculateDistance(x, y, distanceMetric)
    % Compute the distance between vectors x and y based on the distance metric
    switch distanceMetric
        case 'euclidean'
            distance = sqrt(sum((x - y).^2));
        case 'cityblock'
            distance = sum(abs(x - y));
        case 'cosine'
            distance = 1 - dot(x, y) / (norm(x) * norm(y));
        case 'custom'
            distance = sqrt((x(1) - y(:,1)).^2 + 10*(x(2) - y(:,2)).^2);
        otherwise
            error('Invalid distance metric. Supported metrics: euclidean, cityblock, cosine.');
    end
end
```